# Get rid from switch case by using array of functors

Tags: c++

I would like to get rid from switch cases in the below example:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 7; ++i )
    {
            switch (i)
            {
            case 2: case 5: case 6:
                if (value < 0)
                {
                  reportError(param);
                  return;
                }
                break;
            case 3: case 4:
                if (value <= 0)
                {
                  reportError(param);
                  return;
                }
                break;
             default:
                ;
            }
    }
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
    |
                                                        |
                                                       '''   ---- (error)
                                                        '
std::binary_function<double, double, bool> checks[] = { 0, less_equal<double>(), 
                                                        less<double>(), less<double>(),
                                                        less_equal<double>(),
                                                        less_equal<double>(), 
                                                        0 } ; 

for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
   if( bind2nd(checks[i], 0)(value) )    <----- error
   {
      reportError(param);
      return;
   }
}
```

How can I get rid of switch cases(in C++ 98 and without using boost)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind anything.

```
if (checks[i](value, 0))
```

You also don't need an array of functor objects.  Function pointers are just fine for the logic you showed.

```
bool (*(checks[]))(double, double) = { /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
auto always_false = [](double, double) {return false;}
std::function<bool(double,double)> checks = {
  always_false,
  less_equal<double>(),
  less<double>(), less<double>(),
  less_equal<double>(), less_equal<double>(),
  always_false
};

for( int i = 0; i < 7; ++i )
{
  if (checks[i]( 0, value ))
  {
    reportError(param);
    return;
  }
}
```

if your `checks` are as simple as the above and have no state, you can replace the `std::function<bool(double,double)>` with `bool(*)(double, double)`, a raw function pointer.  It will be no less efficient.

Another way to approach this would be to do error-obvlivous programming.

```
boost::optional<ErrorMessage> err;
if (!err && test_1()) err = makeError(param);
if (!err && test_2()) err = makeError(param);
if (!err && test_3()) err = makeError(param);
// ...
if (err)
  reportError(*err);
```

where the code flows through the tests and only does something if a previous test failed and reported an error.